# Load independent LED flasher DIY advice

Tags: relay, switching, 12v, solid-state-relay

I found a product that does something very similar to what I'm trying to DIY.

- The product purposefully combines a load independent digital flasher relay and electronic push-button controls. Depending on how long the respective turn signal push-button is activated, 4 different operating modes are available:
  Short tap on push-button - blink 3x and automatic switch-off.
  Pressing push-button shortly - blink 10x and automatic switch-off.
  ...etc

[image]

- The relay is load independent (1-100 W) and provides a constant flasher frequency to almost all models of LED, micro or halogen turn signal lights as well as 10 or 21 W light bulbs.

Of course there's no details on the components they used on the PCB, so my questions would be, where do I start looking?

My goal is to make it with two functions at most, and if possible, adjustable, so for example short tap on push button could be adjusted, 3x flash, 4...etc.

It's very interesting how small this device is, if anyone can guess what components did they use.

Comment: My guess : a microcontroller to run a blinking program, a power supply for it, and MOSFETs for driving the loads.

Comment: So why do you need to make a copy? use the device. Or are you going to make a better or cheaper one?

Comment: Not really a copy - just something to size down the Arduino based device I made for this same function.

Comment: @Varonne I feel like a 555 timer could probably be used as an astable oscillator instead of the arduino solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ten years ago I needed something similar. This fragment shows a microcontroller, that operates from a charged capacitor while the output stage is active. Today I would probably use an atTiny.

I think this can give you a kick off

[image]

Comment: This winter I've made a device that does the automated flashing according to the sketch, could be customized and everything but since it's Arduino - it requires powering, enclosure, tinkering to install etc. - where as this flasher thing looks as small as a bottle cap, which is something I'd love to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt a microcontroller, a large enough capacitor to hold power on during the flash 'off' and button 'off' times and a MOSFET for switching the load (up to about 6A based on specs). Programming would be a matter of hours, not days, for anyone who is already up to speed on the processor and toolchain. The minimum load (1W) provides enough current to charge the capacitor.

The €30.00 retail price probably has a fair bit of profit margin, but I don't know how many would be sold.

Comment: I'm looking around for some info on the branded unit I linked in the op, and it seems that some people tried to "copy" it using ATTiny85 with a ULN2003 or using MC34063A, but that one has 1.5 current limit.

Comment: Resistor + Zener for power supply, not MC34063A. MOSFET, not ULN2003A.